# Returning structs from Chainlink oracle job

Tags: struct, chainlink

Is it possible to return struct from chainlink oracle job?

I would like to return list of transactions from chainlink job to the contract. So far I've only seen examples where it's possible to return native data types..

Also worth noting that I'm using external adapter in my chainlink job.

```
struct Tx {
    from string;
    to string;
    value string;
}

function fulfill(bytes32 requestId, Tx[] data) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to us return a struct if you used [ABIEncoderV2](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=ABIEncoderV2#abi-coder-pragma).

Comment: How can I serialise response as a struct from job toml config? 